# How can I convert a JavaScript for-loop to CoffeeScript?

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    doStuff();

}
```

That's the JavaScript code that I Want to convert to CoffeeScript.

Comment: Try http://js2.coffee/ too

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
doStuff() for i in [0 .. 9]
```

This is explained on the introduction page: http://coffeescript.org/#loops

**Edit/Update by JP:**

The exact translation is:

```
doStuff() for i in [0...10]
```

You need to be careful with the ".." vs "...", for example:

```
count = 0
doStuff() for i in [0..count] #still executes once!
```

So you think, no problem... I'll just loop until count-1!

```
count = 0
doStuff() for i in [0..count-1] #executes twice!! '0' and then '-1'
```

Literal translation of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someCount; ++i)
  doStuff()
```

is

```
for i in [0...someCount]
  doStuff()
```

Comment: Right, or to translate it literally, `for i in [0...10]`. Two dots (`..`) means "up to and including," while three dots (`...`) means "up to but not including." It's a Ruby-ism.

Comment: The range operators originate from [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) which heavily influenced Ruby. Not sure if Perl invented them or inherited from another ancient language.

Comment: @JP Well if you introduce a variable in the loop the code will behave differently.  For example it will determine runtime which way the counter should go. 0 .. 0 should execute once. 0 .. -1 should execute twice.

Comment: @Bengt exactly. I thought it was an important to modify the answer so that would be internet searchers don't get confused. AFAIR, the CoffeeScript docs aren't clear on this. I got burned by it, I don't want others. I think my additional examples spell this out for people.

Answer (score 20):

The marked answer is functionaly correct but the generated code doesn't match the original javascript.
**The right way** (read, the one closest to the following javascript)

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  doStuff();
}
```

is **`doStuff() for i in [0..someCount] by 1`**
Note the **by 1** on the for loop.

Now this code, still creates an extra `_i` variable. If you can't live with it, then use the following:

```
i=0
while i<=someCount
  doStuff()
  i++
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers work. However, dropping the `i` generates it better for me:

```
for [0...10]
  doStuff()
```

or

```
doStuff() for [0...10]
```

The other solutions add an extra iterator variable `i` for you to use inside of the loop, for example `doStuff(i)`, but from http://coffeescript.org/v1/#loops:

> If you don’t need the current iteration value you may omit it:
>
> `browser.closeCurrentTab() for [0...count]`

In detail, the translation of `for i in [0...10]` is `for (i = j = 0; j < 10; i = ++j)`, whereas the translation of `for [0...10]` is `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.

Note the discussion in other comments about 2-dots versus 3-dots (`[0..9]` vs. `[0...10]`).